# Update widgets after specified time

Tags: python, kivy

I cannot understand how to update kivy screen. 
This is my python file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.1.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import time


class PongGame(Widget):
    labe = ObjectProperty(None)

    def settext(self,x):
        self.labe.text = str(x)
        print "DONE"



class PongApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.settext(1)
        time.sleep(3)
        game.settext(5)
        time.sleep(3)
        game.settext(87)
        time.sleep(3)
        game.settext(5)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

this is my kv file

```
#:kivy 1.0.9
<PongGame>:
    labe:lab
    Label:
        id: lab
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str("Hello")
```

When I run it all it freezes. Then all I see is a 5.
How can i get the others to show up?

Answer (score 3):

```
def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.settext(1)
        time.sleep(3)
        game.settext(5)
        time.sleep(3)
        game.settext(87)
        time.sleep(3)
        game.settext(5)
        return game
```

Your problem is that `sleep` blocks the entire thread - your whole program just stops doing anything for the duration of the call. That includes any graphical interface that has been drawn, it can't update or even receive input because it's running in the same thread and doesn't get run again until your blocking function call has stopped.

Actually, you also have the problem that all these changes take place before the gui is even drawn (the game is displayed in the kivy window only *after* it's returned from `build`).

You have to instead think in terms of kivy's main loop and clock - in the background kivy is trying to run certain functions like touch detection and graphical updates as frequently as possible. If you run some code in this loop that takes a long time, none of the rest of kivy can work until your code terminates. This is normal in gui programming, you always have to be careful not to block the main program loop.

The easiest way in kivy to schedule something regularly is to create a function and hook into this event loop, telling the clock to run your function after some interval or after every repeat of some time period. In your case, you want to change the text every 3 seconds.

Here is a short example of how to achieve exactly what you want:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import time
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from functools import partial
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


Builder.load_string('''
<PongGame>:
    labe:lab
    Label:
        id: lab
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str("Hello")
''')


class PongGame(Widget):
    labe = ObjectProperty(None)

    def settext(self, x, *args):
        self.labe.text = str(x)
        print "DONE"



class PongApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.settext(1)

        Clock.schedule_once(partial(game.settext, 5), 3)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(game.settext, 87), 6)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(game.settext, 5), 9)

        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

There are a few important notes. One is that I used `functools.partial()` because you need to pass a *function* to `Clock.schedule_once`, and `partial` creates a function from an existing function (here `game.settext`) and some default arguments to use (here the numbers for the label). It was also important to add `*args` to `PongGame.settext` because the clock automatically passes some extra arguments that we don't care about.

If the meaning of that is not clear to you, experiment with these parameters to see what happens.